# Telerik MVC Grid submitChanges with no grid changes

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm using Telerik's MVC grid, and I would like to submit batch edit mode changes with some out of grid values.  According to this [telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/grid-with-inline-edit-as-part-of-larger-form.aspx#2232837) I can call the grid's submitChanges function and supply non-grid values inside the OnSubmitChanges event.  This function only gets called if the grid has changes.  There can be a case when values are changed outside of the grid but grid values are not saved.  Is it possible to force the submission so that non-grid values can be submitted?

Answer (score 3):

Good thing Telerik MVC Extensions are open source.  I figured out the answer the following way:

```
function SaveCriteriaChanges() {
    var grid = $("#MyGridId").data("tGrid");

    //don't submit if grid fails validation
    if (!grid.validate())
        return false;

    if (grid.hasChanges()) {
        grid.submitChanges();
    } else { //no grid changes to process so force submission
        var additionalValues = {};
        if(!$.telerik.trigger(grid.element, 'submitChanges', { values: additionalValues })) {
            grid.sendValues($.extend({}, additionalValues), 'updateUrl', 'submitChanges');
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```